# Dynamic form builder forms and database design?

Tags: architecture, database, webforms

Say your users can create their own web-based forms (textboxes, selects, etc) and publish them on the web for their users to fill out.

Does anyone have a resource or any advice on how to architect the database to tie into the dynamic forms?

For example, would you create a child table for each form, or different versions of a given form?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Creating new tables dynamically based on user input is usually not a good idea. If the basic structure of forms changes, all the dynamically created tables will need to be updated to include new columns or have old ones removed, and this can cause maintenance headaches. Then there's problem of knowing which table to query (which will probably lead to dynamic SQL which opens up all new problems). And there's probably performance problems too, but I'm not certain how bad that would be. Also, a table is usually used to represent a *type* of entity (such as "web form") rather than having copies of the same table for each new *instance* of the same entity.

I'd suggest a single table for the forms. You'll need an identifier on each form to identify whose form it is:

```
forms
-----
  id (PK)
  name
  owner_id (FK to users.id)
  (other fields)

form_elements
-------------
  id (PK)
  form_id (FK to forms.id)
  element_type_id (FK to element_types.id)
  caption
  (other fields)

element_types
-------------
  id (PK)
  name

element_list_values
-------------------
  id (PK)
  element_id (FK to form_elements.id)
  name
  value
  (other fields??)
```

Your web application can let users create forms which will be saved in the `forms` tables, with a reference to the user that created (assuming that you are tracking users as proper entities). The form is populated with `form_elements` that reference the `forms` table so they know which form they belong to, and the `element_types` so they know which type they are. `element_types` will store a static (mostly) list of different elements a form can have. Types could be: "text_field", "drop_down_list", "radio_buttons", "checkbox". For types such as "drop_down_list" and "radio_buttons", you'll need an extra table, maybe called `element_list_values` to store the possible options for the lists that these elements normally have.

Comment: Great solution.  TY

Comment: do you know of any existing web form builder GUI tools to use to populate the table schema you outlined above by chance?  We're using .NET if relevant.  TY.

Comment: @JeffBorden: No, but I'm sure there is something out there.

Comment: So I'm assuming that the best way to record submitted forms would be with a schema like: 
**form_submissions**
id (PK)
form_id (FK to forms.id)
user_id (FK to users.id)
...

**form_submission_elements**
id (PK)
form_submission_id (FK to form_submissions.id)
form_element_id (FK to forms_elements.id)
value
Look right-ish?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner How would an select to generate table from the form fields and the fields values in this schema!?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I agree with the above designs.. but for newly added form fields, how do I store data? For e.g. http://goo.gl/at66tx

Comment: I did that once more ore less like that for a research project,  but the element_list_values would go over 100Million records this way.  It caused performance issues (some 15y. ago though)

Comment: I guess element_list_values is the table we should refer to to know what a user selected?